# Connect remote Hive server in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyspark, hive, bigdata

I am learning Pyspark and Hive. Currently, I want to connect to Hive remote server from VS Code. I would like to access the table and do some ETL using pyspark and write the new table back to the HIVE server. I am using the windows operating system and python language. Any help, documentation, or links are greatly appreciated.

The details of the hive connection is shown below.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [remote-ssh](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) to connect to the sever.

Then you can operate in the remote workspace.

Comment: Thanks, @MingJie-MSFT. I will surely Checkout.

Comment: I have added more details of the connection that has to be made. It would be really helpful if I could get more assistance.

Comment: You can read [document about Remote-SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), and [HDInsight Tools for VSCode： Hive Table Preview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/hdinsight-tools-for-vscode-hive-table-preview/)